# Close/Open project automatically using ant build?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

As the tittle, Is there any way to Close/Open a project in workspace using ant build? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Eclipse provides many Ant task wrappers, it does not provide such for Eclipse's ResourcesPlugin, through which an IProject reference could be used to programmatically open, close, and manage other project settings.

The only available task related to projects is `<eclipse.refreshLocal>` Nor, does there seem to be any readily available 3rd-party plugin that would expose such methods.